# React not Detecting my .env File with the Correct REACT_APP_ Prefix

Tags: node.js, reactjs, environment-variables, development-environment

For some reason, my React Project will not detect my .env file even though I am using the correct REACT_APP_ prefix. I get an error that states "'REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL' is not defined". The backend portion works fine ("I have other variables in the .env file but I'm hiding them for privacy").

.env

```
REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL=http://localhost:5000
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import axios from 'axios';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL;
REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL;
console.log(REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "full-stack-red-panda",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.mjs",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node backend/server.mjs",
    "server": "nodemon backend/server.mjs",
    "client": "npm start --prefix frontend",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "data:import": "node backend/seederScript.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "dotenv": "^9.0.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-async-handler": "^1.1.4",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.10",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.14.8",
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0",
    "concurrently": "^6.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

Thank you for looking over this reader :)

EDIT: Upon further research I have found out that the index.js file can read my PORT variable but not the REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL variable, Odd...

Comment: Do you mean `console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL)`?

Comment: Sadly that did not work, thanks for helping though!